# elasticsearch-dsl - how to get sequence number and primary term?

Tags: elasticsearch-dsl, django-elasticsearch-dsl

I have a containerised setup. I have a `web` container running django and separate `es` container.
I am using the following in my `web` container

- `elasticsearch-dsl==7.4.0`
- `django-elasticsearch-dsl==7.2.2`

I have a django model, a document (as per `django-elasticsearch-dsl` docs) and a view. I can save/query fine. It works

How can I find the sequence number / `seq_no` and primary term / `primary_term` of the Document? Neither package's search or response objects contain these (and they aren't mentioned in the docs).